# ExtJS ref to panel element with specific title

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, reference, extjs4.2

I am working on a project in **ExtJS 4.2** written in the **MVC** pattern. I need a reference to a specific item inside **MyViewport** (extended from the class **Ext.container.Viewport**). The item which needs to be referenced from within the controller has the Class **MyPanel** (extended from "Ext.Panel"). Problem is there are several items with the same class, so simply doing a standart ExtJs-**component-query** like,

```
//inside myController.js
refs: [
    ...
    {ref: 'specificItem', selector: 'MyViewport_alias > myPanel_alias'},
    ...
]
```

wont get me a reference to the item. Thats why i thought of retrieving the reference by something like this, since the items using **MyPanel-class** have a property **title**:

```
//inside myController.js
refs: [
    ...
    {ref: 'specificItem', 
     selector: 'MyViewport_alias > myPanel_alias > title="title of specific item"'},
    ...
]
```

But i coulnd't find any examples on retrieving items as references by using their **properties as parts of the component query** other than [this](http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-3).

Has someone experience with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Component queries in ExtJS are very similar to [*CSS* query selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors).  You could find a component by a specific property with syntax similar to: `"... > [title=My Component Title]"` - that said, using the *"title"* sounds like **really bad practice**.

At worst, as a visible part of the user-interface it's very sensitive to change - easily breaking your application and at best it immediately limits your application's language-support and configurability.

Ideally you should be utilising the `itemId` property as a more **robust** way of referencing components.

[**» fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7rf)

---

I hadn't noticed that *4.2* didn't support attribute selectors - the component query functionality seems to have always drawn inspiration from *CSS* though, so unfortunately if it's only a recent development it doesn't look like there's any way to do what you want using this method.

You'd have to manually fetch the component and/or create your own reference.  You *can* select by `xtype` / `alias` in *4.2* and then apply a filter to the result, for example:

```js
Ext.Array.filter(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel'), function(x){
    return !!x.title.match('Sub Panel 2');
}).shift();
```

<sup>*( Obviously no use in a controller's `refs` )*</sup>

[**» fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7ro)

---

... this is however ugly - all the more reason to use `itemId`'s properly.  There was already an example of this in action in the first fiddle.  All you need to do is assign an alphanumeric string (no spaces) to the property - these don't strictly *need* to be unique but it's generally preferable.  Then in your selector simply prefix a hash `#` in front of the string which indicates to the engine that you are looking for a component with a specific *ID*.

`itemId` selectors definitely work in *4.2* so without seeing your code I can only speculate as to what the problem is.  In your post you are using `>` which narrows the query to **direct descendants** only.  Are you *absolutely sure* that the component you are looking for is a child of `myPanel_alias` and not wrapped up in another container?  ***i.e.***

```
"myPanel_alias #myItemId"      <-- try this
"myPanel_alias > #myItemId"    <-- instead of this
```

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle example, but its not working on ExtJs 4.2.

Comment: And can you probably give an example with itemId, as i cant get it work neither in ExtJs 5 nor in ExtJs 4.2?

Comment: var foo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myPanel > panel #second');
    foo.update('edit success'); doesn't work, but the ugly approach does work. I added itemId: 'second' to the second panel-item inside #myPanel.

Comment: @kiltek the **space** between `panel` and `#second` is also important. What you've posted there reads as *"Find component with ID myPanel and fetch the first child panel - then look down it's hierarchy for another component with ID second"* whereas `#myPanel > panel#second`, reads as *"Find component with ID myPanel and look specifically for a child panel with ID second"* - see the difference?  If you have any more issues I'd recommend posting a fiddle which would allow me to see your actual component structure.

Comment: thank you for your patience. can you point me to the extjs 4.2 documentation which describes this magical behaviour?

Comment: [`Ext.ComponentQuery` *(v5)*](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) [`Ext.ComponentQuery` *(v4)*](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) - they have some good examples.  The whole engine is modelled on *CSS* selectors though - It's a little lengthy but it's worth reading up on the [selector level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) if you have time.  Even if some parts don't exist in ExtJS yet - It's the kind of stuff you can expect to see in the future.